# Реинициализация slick слайдера

Tags: slider, filter, slick.js

Магазин на wordpress при фитрации товаров плагином Advanced AJAX Product Filters, отваливается слайдер slick; 
На забугорных форумах прочитал о `$('.slider-products').slick('unslick');`, но попытки его перезапустить во время фильтрации успехом не увенчались...
Как можно его перезапустить при фильтрации?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заработало, действительно перед фильтрацией прописал

```
$('.slider-products').slick('unslick');
```

и после

```
$('.slider-products').slick();
```

Вопрос закрыт.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не забудьте принять Ваш ответ, чтобы вопрос не оставался открытым.

Comment: `$('.slider-products').slick('unslick').slick();` - а так можно?